# Setting macOS's `isDocumentEdited` status in Tauri

Tags: tauri

I'm new to Tauri (and Rust) and trying to set my app window's `isDocumentEdited` status (a macOS-only feature). I found a [feature request](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tao/issues/268) that seems to indicate that Tauri supports this, which includes a brief example:

```rust
Event::MainEventsCleared => {

   // Change window document_edited status every other second
   let clock: bool = (start_time.elapsed().as_secs) % 2) = 0;
   window.set_is_document_edited(clock);
   assert_eq!(window.is_document_edited(), clock);
}
```

However, when I invoke `set_is_document_edited` method on a window in Tauri, the compiler throws an error. Additionally, I can't find any reference to it in the [Tauri source](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Atauri-apps%2Ftauri+document_edited&type=code).

It looks like this is a feature of the upstream crate TAO, not Tauri itself — but I don't understand how the above example is working.

When I try to use the equivalent method:

```rust
let window = app.get_window("main").unwrap(); // works
window.set_is_document_edited(true); // doesn't work
```

The compiler throws an error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `set_is_document_edited` found for struct `Window` in the current scope
window.set_is_document_edited(true);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Window`
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: The feature request you showed only means that it's supported in tao = tauri's windowing library. It still needs to be explicitly exposed in tauri itself, which is why https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/3125 is still open.

Comment: Ah! That's helpful clarification, thank you.